# Should i delete the posts created by a plugin on uninstall?

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types

I created a plugin which is based on a Custom Post Type.
When someone uninstalls this plugin, should i delete the posts under this post type or i should just leave them untouched?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is borderline "not constructive", because it's going to solicit opinion rather than objective fact or expertise.

That said: my *opinion* is:

1. By default the Plugin should not touch user-generated content
2. It would be considerate to offer a "delete content" checkbox option at uninstall